# What is the problem in this timer [JS]

Tags: javascript, time, timer, setinterval

What is the problem in this timer [JS]

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var remain = "14:14";
    setInterval ("timer()", 660);

    function timer(){

        var remainM = parseInt(remain.split(":")[0]);
        var remainS = parseInt(remain.split(":")[1]);

        //document.getElementById("hello").innerHTML = parseInt(remainS);

        if (remainS==0) {
            if (remainM==0) {

            } else {
                remainM = parseInt(remainM) - 1;
                remainS = 59;
            }
        } else {
            remainS = parseInt(remainS) - 1;
        }

        var remainSr = String(remainS);
        var remainMr = String(remainM);

        if (parseInt(remainS)<=9) {remainSr = "0" + String(remainS);}
        if (parseInt(remainM)<=9) {remainMr = "0" + String(remainM);}

        remain = String(remainMr) + ":" + String(remainSr);
        document.getElementById("hello").innerHTML = remain;

    }

</script>
```

It jumps from 14:09 to 13:59

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is historical mistake made by ignoring the second parameter of parseInt.

Check this article: http://www.devguru.com/technologies/ecmascript/quickref/parseint.html

Try this version:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var remain = "14:14";
setInterval("timer()", 660);

function timer() {
    var remainM = parseInt(remain.split(":")[0], 10);
    var remainS = parseInt(remain.split(":")[1], 10); 
    if (remainS == 0) {
        if (remainM == 0) {} else {
            remainM = parseInt(remainM) - 1;
            remainS = 59;
        }
    } else {
        remainS = parseInt(remainS) - 1;
    }
    var remainSr = String(remainS);
    var remainMr = String(remainM);
    if (parseInt(remainS) <= 9) {
        remainSr = "0" + String(remainS);
    }
    if (parseInt(remainM) <= 9) {
        remainMr = "0" + String(remainM);
    }
    remain = String(remainMr) + ":" + String(remainSr);
    document.getElementById("hello").innerHTML = remain;
}
</script>
```

Comment: Number() can avoid those issues.

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify the radix in `parseInt`.  If you do `parseInt("09")`, you are asking to parse the octal number 9, which is an error.  See the [parseInt documentation on MDC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt#Description)

Answer (score 2):

`parseInt("09")` returns 0. if you change it to `parseFloat` or `parseInt("09", 10)` it will work.

Answer (score 1):

Others have covered the immediate problem — that you're accidentally treating a number as octal rather than decimal — but the deeper problem is that you're storing numbers as strings. Constantly converting to and from strings is convoluted and error-prone. A better design would be to store the time as two numbers and have a function that converts those numbers into a string on demand. Here's a version that keeps the numbers and their string representation separate:

```
var remain = {
    mins: 14, 
    secs: 14,
    toString: function () {
        var pad = function(num) { return (num < 10 ? "0" : "") + num; };
        return pad(this.mins) + ":" + pad(this.secs);
    }
};

setInterval (timer, 660);

function timer() {
    if (remain.secs === 0) {
        if (remain.mins > 0) {
            remain.mins -= 1;
            remain.secs = 59;
        }
    } else {
        remain.secs -= 1;
    }
    document.document.getElementById("hello").innerHTML = remain;
}
```

Comment: +1.  Holy smokes, that is nearly exactly the answer I was just getting ready to post.  Right down to adding a toString function that calls a pad function.  It's erie.

Answer (score -1):

The `parseInt()` method actually returns the FIRST integer it finds, therefore you are getting back 0 from '09' when you're expecting 9. Try using the `parseFloat()` method there, and you should be golden. It will return '9' which is what you're expecting. I hope this helps!!

Comment: It doesn't work as you say, parseInt('09') returns zero because the leading zero (in most browsers) makes it treat the number as octal. Since '09' doesn't exist in octal (there is no 9), parseInt returns zero. The more common ways to convert a string to a number are unary +, e.g. x = +t, or using Number as a function, e.g. x = Number(t)

Answer (score -1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<button onclick="Timer()">Try it</button>

<script>
function Timer() {
    var sec=0;
    var mm =0;
    setInterval(function(){
            if(sec<10){
               if(mm>=10) {
                  document.getElementById('p1').innerHTML= mm + ":"+ "0"+sec;
               }
               else {
                                  document.getElementById('p1').innerHTML= "0"+mm + ":"+ "0"+sec;
                               }
                               sec = sec+1;                             
            }
            else if(sec >=10 && sec <= 59) {
               if(mm>=10) {
                  document.getElementById('p1').innerHTML= mm + ":"+ sec;
               }
               else {
                                  document.getElementById('p1').innerHTML= "0"+mm + ":"+ sec;
                               } 
                               sec = sec+1;
                            }
                            else if(sec==60) {
                                     sec=0;
                                     mm = mm+1;
                                     if(mm>=10) {
                                        document.getElementById('p1').innerHTML= mm + ":"+ "0"+sec;
                                     }
                                     else {
                                        document.getElementById('p1').innerHTML= "0"+mm + ":"+ "0"+sec;
                                     }
                               sec = sec+1;            
                            }
                },1000);
}
</script>
<p id="p1"></p>
</body>
</html>
```